# select ngmodel not binding the variable

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel

I have a very simple page with two selects filled in with same data (bank accounts). One is aimed to be source and another target in order to create a transaction. In this simple scenario a transaction is just an amount transfered from one account to another.

I am facing a problem while sending the transaction to my rest service. From the image bellow is easy to see that the transaction variable isn't properly filled but I don't know what is going wrong.

I see the first account (source) from transaction partially filled and the second (target) with [object Object]. Why wasn't filled the same since they are exactly same type of object and why in the first one name wasn't filled?

new-transaction.html:

```
<div>
  <div>
  <label>Source Account</label>
  <select [(ngModel)]="transaction.sourceAccount"> 

      <option *ngFor="let a of accounts" [value]="a" >{{a.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Target Account</label>
  <select  [(ngModel)]="transaction.targetAccount" > 
      <option *ngFor="let a of accounts" [value]="a">{{a.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="transaction.amount">
</div>
<div>
    <button (click)="addTransaction()">Add</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

new-transaction.component.ts

```
...
export class NewTransactionComponent implements OnInit {

  accounts: Account[];
  transaction: Transaction = new Transaction();

  constructor(private accountService: AccountService, private transactionService: TransactionService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.transaction.targetAccount = new Account();
    this.transaction.sourceAccount = new Account();

    this.accountService
    .getAllAccounts()
    .subscribe(
      (accounts) => {
        this.accounts = accounts;
      }
    );
  }

  addTransaction(): void {
    this.transactionService.addTransaction(this.transaction)    
    .subscribe(
      (transaction) => {
        this.transaction = transaction;
      }
    );
    //this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  } 
}
```

transaction.service.ts

...

```
  public addTransaction(transaction: Transaction): Observable<Transaction> {
    return this.http
      .post(API_URL + '/transaction', transaction)
      .map(response => {
        return new Transaction(response.json());
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

transaction.ts

```
import { Account } from "./account";

export class Transaction {
    idtransaction: number;
    amount: number;
    sourceAccount: Account;
    targetAccount: Account;

    constructor(values: Object = {}) {
      Object.assign(this, values);
    }
}
```

account.ts

```
import { User } from "./user";

export class Account {
    id: number;
    name: string = '';
    user: User[] = [];

    constructor(values: Object = {}) {
      Object.assign(this, values);
    }
}
```

[image]

*** edited

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working with the following code. I like what Garth posted, and it would be less code, too. I had this ready just minutes after seeing his answer, so I am going to post it since I spent some time on it.

*new-transaction.component.html*

```
<div>
  <div>
  <label>Source Account</label>
  <select [(ngModel)]="sourceBankAccount" name="sourceBankAccount" (change)="sourceAccountChanged($event.target.value)" >

      <option *ngFor="let a of accounts" [value]="a.id" >{{a.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Target Account</label>
  <select  [(ngModel)]="targetBankAccount"  name="targetBankAccount" (change)="targetAccountChanged($event.target.value)" >
      <option *ngFor="let a of accounts" [value]="a.id">{{a.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="transaction.amount">
</div>
<div>
    <button (click)="addTransaction()">Add</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Notice that this uses the account id for the value in the drop down. There are `change` event calls here, too.

*new-transaction.component.ts*

```
export class NewTransactionComponent implements OnInit {

  accounts: BankAccount[];
  transaction: Transaction = new Transaction();
  sourceBankAccount: number;
  targetBankAccount: number;

  constructor(private accountService: BankAccountService, private transactionService: TransactionService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.accountService
    .getAllAccounts()
    .subscribe(
      (accounts) => {
        this.accounts = accounts;
      }
    );
  }

  sourceAccountChanged(account: number) {
    const newAccount: BankAccount = this.accounts.find(acct => acct.id === +account);
    if (newAccount) {
      this.transaction.sourceAccount = new BankAccount(newAccount);
    }
  }

  targetAccountChanged(account: number) {
    const newAccount: BankAccount = this.accounts.find(acct => acct.id === +account);
    if (newAccount) {
      this.transaction.targetAccount = new BankAccount(newAccount);
    }
  }

  addTransaction(): void {
    console.log(this.transaction);
    this.transactionService.addTransaction(this.transaction)
    .subscribe(
      (transaction) => {
        this.transaction = transaction;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this solution would also work - I've used this with <select> fields quite a bit. But as you said, more code for this particular scenario.

Comment: Kindly, can you see the picture just added? I am getting undefined when I choose the account

Comment: Sorry, ignore my last comment. It was a typo

Comment: definitely you answered my question. As a plus if you don't mind, why after I choose the account the select box doesn't show the option selected?

Comment: I am not seeing that problem in the code that I am using. When I select something in the account dropdowns, it shows what I selected. I didn't add any styling into my project, but I doubt anything like that might affect anything.

Comment: I do see in your screenshot that the name of the source account is empty. Could that be why you are not seeing anything?

Comment: I don't see that error either, works ok for me.
Also noticed that rather than using the (change) event you could instead tap hook into (ngModelChange) - so then you don't need to pass the $event.target.value parameter, just pickup the current value of the model e.g. targetBankAccount

Answer (score 12):

I think you're missing the use of the `ngValue` directive here to have the object 
reflected in the value bound to `ngModel`.

```
<label>Target Account</label>
<select  [(ngModel)]="transaction.targetAccount" > 
    <option *ngFor="let a of accounts" [ngValue]="a">{{a.name}}</option>
</select>
```

From the documentation ..  *If your option values happen to be objects (and you'd like to save the selection in your form as an object), use ngValue instead*.

See here for the full docs for the [select element.](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor)

Note I'm not sure why it seems to be working on the `sourceAccount` property.